# Clojure - return new sequence from existing with side effect

Tags: clojure, maps, seq

I have an issue that I've run into and not sure how to approach. Basically, I have a database call which returns a sequence of maps. I need to apply a change to a specific element of each map, and then get back a new sequence with all the same values except the one I've changed.

I currently have the following, which iterates through the sequence and prints it, but I'm not sure how to actually build the new one.

```
(defn find-character-by-id []
  (let [
      character (mc/find-maps db "characters" {:user_id "5b4403d3c1025107593fa0b4" })
    ]
    (doseq [s character]
      (println s))))
```

an example map might be:

```
{:_id #object[org.bson.types.ObjectId 0x74bb0de6 5b467e5bc102511a1729a0f1], :user_id 5b4403d3c1025107593fa0b4, :value 20}
```

My goal right now is to be able to apply a custom function to cover the _id to a string, but I might also want to add an arbitrary amount to value so something generic is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to convert each `:_id` to a string using some `to-str` function, you could write:

```
(mapv ; Turn characters into a modified vector
  #(update % :_id to-str) ; by updating each map :_id using to-str
  characters)
```

I'm `map`ping over each map, then `update`ing the `:_id` of each by applying `to-str` to each `:_id` val.

Any time you want to turn one list into another list of an equal length, use `map` or `mapv`. You can also use `for` if you need some filtering capability.

Any time you want to change a value associated with a key in a map based on its old value, use `update`.

I'm just combining the two here.

`doseq` should really only be used when you're iterating without the intent of creating a new list, or the new list you're creating is being created via some mutation. It doesn't evaluate to anything useful.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for the detailed explanation as well!